# Makefile: loop over folder and merge files into a new file

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a folder `/jobs` and I am trying to merge every files present within that folder into a new file called `workflows.yaml` with a new line between each file merged.

I am able to loop over the directory using

```
for FILE in jobs/*; do awk $$FILE > workflows.yaml
```

And I am also able to merge

```
awk '{print}' jobs/a.yaml jobs/b.yaml > workflows.yaml
```

What I tried but did not work:

```
for FILE in jobs/*; do echo $$FILE; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need awk, ed, etc.  At least I don't see why based on the question.  Isn't this good enough:

```
all:
         for f in jobs/*; do cat $$f; echo; done > workflows.yml
```

?  If not perhaps you could be clear in your question about exactly what you want to do.  When you say "a new line" do you mean, a blank line?

Comment: Yes,  a blank line, Thanks